# Laravel Uncaught Type Error (Cannot set property elements of #<HTMLFormElement> which has only a getter)

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, posts

```js
function makeSerializable(elem) {
    return $(elem).prop('elements', $('*', elem).addBack().get());
}

---------------------------------------------------

function newPost(){
    var form_name = '#form-new-post';

    $(form_name + ' .loading-post').show();

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('data', JSON.stringify(makeSerializable(form_name).serializeJSON()));

    var file_inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.image-input');
    $(file_inputs).each(function(index, input) {
        data.append('image', input.files[0]);
    });
```

Wondering if anybody can help with this head scratcher?? The function is trying to submit a new post (obviously) I'm really new to this and trying to understand why this call is returning an error and a function not functioning! 2 different javascript files calling/using the function. I cant understand the returning error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property elements of # which has only a getter" any help??

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Don't see the connection between the code and the error. If it's a laravel error, you should have some php code

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! Was the simplest of problems. A clash of jQuery files. Just had to remove the old ones still being called.